# How to use MongoDB extended operators in Loopback 4?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback, loopback4

I'm working with **loopback v4** and I need to use the MongoDB `$unset` extended operator. Documentation on MongoDB connector indirectly states that it can be used (see [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MongoDB-connector.html#additional-properties)) , but I can't find any example/documentation on how is it supposed to be used on my repository, do you have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to modify the settings in `DataSource` first.

xxx.datasource.ts

```js
export class XxxDataSource extends juggler.DataSource {
    static dataSourceName = '...';

    constructor() {
        super({
            "name": "...",
            "connector": "mongodb",
            "url": "...",
            "database": "...",
            "allowExtendedOperators": true // <= !!!! default is false
        });
    }
}
```

xxx.controller.ts

```js
return await this.xxxRepository.updateById(
    "....id....",
    {
        $unset: {
            test: ""
        }
    } as any // <= !!!! you can using `$unset` now, add `as any` to avoid type error
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Zhikai Xiong! Actually I already enabled extended operator in my datasource connection, but I was stuck on `updateById()` because I missed the `as any` to allow ts compilation!